# Bedtools wrongly indicates zero coverage

Tags: bedtools, coverage

I have a BAM file produced using BWA-MEM and I need to calculate the coverage of each exon in this sequencing. I tried using this command:

`bedtools coverage -a exome_sorted.bed -b exome_alignment.bam -sorted`

And the result was the following:

```
chr1    12595   12802   ref|DDX11L1,ref|NR_046018,ens|ENST00000518655,ens|ENST00000450305,ens|ENST00000456328,ens|ENST00000515242  .       ref|DDX11L1     0       0       207     0.0000000
chr1    13163   13658   ref|DDX11L1,ref|NR_046018,ens|ENST00000518655,ens|ENST00000450305,ens|ENST00000456328,ens|ENST00000515242  .       ref|DDX11L1     0       0       495     0.0000000
chr1    14620   15015   ref|WASH7P,ref|NR_024540,ens|ENST00000538476,ens|ENST00000438504,ens|ENST00000488147,ens|ENST00000541675,ens|ENST00000423562       .       ref|WASH7P      0       0       395     0.0000000
...
```

That is, zero coverage for all exons. But there are reads mapping to the exons, as I can see by opening my BAM file on IGV and looking at some exonic regions:

[image: IGV view of the exonic region chr1:12,595-12,802 , clearly showing many reads mapping.]

I have already tried sorting the BED file using `sort -k1,1 -k2,2n` ([as recommended on the Bedtools documentation](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/coverage.html)) and using `bedtools sort` with the `-faidx` option, but neither option solved my issue.

if I skip the `-sorted` option, the memory usage becomes way too high.

I have also checked if the chromosome names are the same in the BAM file and in the BED file, using `samtools view -H`. Both use `chr1,chr2,...,chr22,chrX,chrY`, although BAM has `chrM` and stuff like `chrUn_gl000214` which are not on the BED.

Thanks!

EDIT:

@ATpoint pointed out that all visible reads in this region have MAPQ0. I looked at another exon that did not have this issue, but Bedtools still outputs zero coverage. IGV picture below:

[image: IGV view of the exonic region chr1:12,595-12,802 , clearly showing many reads mapping.]

Answer (score 2):

If this is your output :

```
chr1    12595   12802   ref|DDX11L1,ref|NR_046018,ens|ENST00000518655,ens|ENST00000450305,ens|ENST00000456328,ens|ENST00000515242  .       ref|DDX11L1     0       0       207     0.0000000
```

Then I guess your bedfile looks like this (the first 6 fields) :

- chrom : chr1
- FeatureStart : 12595
- FeatureEnd : 12802
- name : ref|DDX11L1,ref|NR_046018,ens|ENST00000518655,ens|ENST00000450305,ens|ENST00000456328,ens|ENST00000515242
- score : .
- strand : ref|DDX11L1

The issue I see here is that you are giving the wrong information to the strand field of your bedfile. It should be either `+`, either `-` or `.` if you don't want to consider the strand information.

Hope it helps !